# jquery UI-Multiselect change header text color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I am using the Jquery UI-Multiselect to add functionality to my dropdown list.

I have managed to change the background colour of the header but am unable to change the text colour.

Below is the css for the multiselect:

```
.ui-multiselect { padding:2px 0 2px 4px; text-align:left;background:#fff;color:#000 !important;}
.ui-multiselect span.ui-icon { float:right }
.ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes input {      
position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; left:-9999px; }
.ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { padding:5px !
important }
.ui-multiselect-header { margin-bottom:3px; padding:3px 0 3px 4px; }
.ui-multiselect-header ul { font-size:0.9em; }
.ui-multiselect-header ul li { float:left; padding:0 10px 0 0; }
.ui-multiselect-header a { text-decoration:none; }
.ui-multiselect-header a:hover { text-decoration:underline }
.ui-multiselect-header span.ui-icon { float:left }
.ui-multiselect-header li.ui-multiselect-close { float:right; text- 
align:right; padding-right:0;}
.ui-multiselect-menu { display:none; padding:3px; position:absolute; z-
index:10000; text-align: left; }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes { position:relative /* fixes bug in IE6/7 */; 
overflow-y:auto }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { cursor:default; display:block; 
border:1px solid transparent; padding:3px 1px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes label input { position:relative; top:1px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li { clear:both; font-size:0.9em; padding-
right:3px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label { text-
align:center; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px solid }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label a { 
display:block; padding:3px; margin:1px 0; text-decoration:none }/* remove 
label borders in IE6 because IE6 does not support transparency */
* html .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { border:none }
```

Comment: Without your Html code, we won't be able to help, do post your HTML or if possible just fiddle it.

Comment: There is no html, it uses MVC/razor . The formatting is handled by css not html

Answer (score 0):

This is super old but you can override the CSS like this

```
.ui-multiselect-all span { padding-left: 10px; color: #000000 !important}
```

`!important` just depends on the load order of your CSS files. might be unnecessary